# receiveApproval contract function

Tags: contract-development

I'll be happy to get some clarifications on this function.
Some usage example can be found here:
https://github.com/Giveth/minime/blob/master/contracts/MiniMeToken.sol

Rows 31-31:

> contract ApproveAndCallFallBack {
>       function receiveApproval(address from, uint256 _amount, address _token, bytes _data) public;
>   }

Rows 247-266:

```
function approveAndCall(address _spender, uint256 _amount, bytes _extraData
) public returns (bool success) {
    require(approve(_spender, _amount));

    ApproveAndCallFallBack(_spender).receiveApproval(
        msg.sender,
        _amount,
        this,
        _extraData
    );

    return true;
}
```

I don't see an implementation of the function in the contracts code but just declaring and calling it.

Comment: Any link about what you are talking about?

Comment: i saw now a discussion that help me a little bit:
https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/36041/how-does-the-erc20-tutorial-instantiate-an-unimplemented-interface

Answer (score 2):

receiveApproval function need to be implemented in service contract.

If token contract receives tokens via 'approveAndCall', it passes all values to receiveApproval which is in the service contract.

_spender is address of service contract.

I'm Korean and my english is not good but I hope you can understand what I'm saying.