# How does the ERC20 tutorial instantiate an unimplemented interface?

Tags: solidity, tokens, interfaces

I've been going through [the official Ethereum token tutorial](https://www.ethereum.org/token) and I noticed that the provided token code includes the following lines within the `approveAndCall` function:

```
tokenRecipient spender = tokenRecipient(_spender);
if (approve(_spender, _value)) {
    spender.receiveApproval(msg.sender, _value, this, _extraData);
    return true;
}
```

I'm confused how this works and what it does. Given that `tokenRecipient` is an interface [0] without a corresponding implementation, how can and why does `approveAndCall` call `tokenRecipient`'s constructor and its `receiveApproval` method? While I can imagine that unimplemented interfaces like `tokenRecipient` might have default constructors and no-op implementations, I still don't see why `approveAndCall` would then call `receiveApproval` on the returned `tokenRecipient` contract.

At first, I was thinking that Solidity had copied Go and allowed implicit interface implementation i.e. if a contract and interface have matching methods and signatures, the contract implements that interface. But even that doesn't explain this case because the token contracts in this tutorial **don't** include `receiveApproval` implementations and therefore aren't implicitly implementing the `tokenRecipient` interface.

The only other option I can think of is that we're assuming that there's a `tokenRecipient` implementation that corresponds to the address passed in to `approveAndCall` as `_spender`. Is that what's happening? If so, I wish the tutorial made that more clear.

[0] `tokenRecipient` has the following signature.

```
interface tokenRecipient { 
    function receiveApproval(
        address _from, uint256 _value, address _token, bytes _extraData
    ) public; 
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The only other option I can think of is that we're assuming that there's a `tokenRecipient` implementation that corresponds to the address passed in to `approveAndCall` as `_spender`

You got it right. `tokenRecipient(_spender)` is sort of like casting `_spender` to a `tokenRecipient`.

Comment: So what would happen if there wasn't a `tokenRecipient` at that address? Would the transaction fail?

Comment: That's up to the contract at that address. The contract will be sent a message selecting the `receiveApproval` function. If it implements that function or implements a fallback function and doesn't `revert`/`throw`, then that call will succeed.